# Django: Get serialized object in save hook

Tags: django

Use case: On save for some of my models, I need to serialize them and send the serialized object somewhere (logging, emails etc). There's some additional things that need to happen with the serialized object. The important thing is that I need this serialized object on a save hook as there are multiple ways my model can be saved (via Rest, Django Admin, etc). However, since Django serializers import the model its serializing, this creates a circular reference.

Before jumping to Signals, it should be noted that Signals have some limitations and are considered an [anti-pattern](https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html).

Ideally, I would like to use [Django Lifecycle](https://rsinger86.github.io/django-lifecycle/) hooks, which are considered a more suitable and reliable hook at the model level. But this still doesn't solve the issue of calling a serializer on a save hook in a Django model.

So besides explicitly calling the serializer and save methods at the View level, is there a way to serialize the object at the model's save operation?

Comment: For any action which isn't part of the core business logic and is "somewhat optional" like logging or triggering internal email notifications, signals are actually the perfectly appropriate tool IMO.

Comment: @deceze In this case, it is very much a part of the core business logic and definitely not optional. Given there's an entire web page dedicated to saying not use them, it's hard for me to be convinced otherwise.